# No USB device recognized libusbJava/ubuntu 13.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, libusb

I am trying to write some communication with USB converter with CP2102 chip under Linux. Can anyone help me, why this is not working?

> *ondra@ondra-notebook:~$ lsusb
>
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2805 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
>
>   Bus 003 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
>
>   Bus 004 Device 025: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth
>
>   Bus 008 Device 004: ID 09da:0080 A4 Tech Co., Ltd
>
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
>   Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>
>   Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>
>   Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
>
>   Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
>   Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
>   Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
>   Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub*

---

Java code is here:

```
import ch.ntb.usb.*;

public class libUSB_example2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */

static long handle = 0;         //Device-Handle
int retval = 0;                 //used for return values
byte[] dummybyte = new byte[1]; //used by specific write-functions as value to write (empty)

final int I2C_M_RD = 0x01;  
final int STATUS_IDLE        = 0;
final int STATUS_ADDRESS_ACK = 1;
final int STATUS_ADDRESS_NAK = 2;  
final int I2C_TINY_USB_VID = 0x0403;
final int I2C_TINY_USB_PID = 0xc631;
final int USB_TYPE_CLASS = (0x01 << 5);
final int USB_TYPE_VENDOR = (0x02 << 5); 
final int USB_ENDPOINT_IN = 0x80;
final int USB_ENDPOINT_OUT  = 0x00;    
final int USB_CTRL_IN = (USB_TYPE_CLASS | USB_ENDPOINT_IN);
final int USB_CTRL_OUT = (USB_TYPE_CLASS);  
final int CMD_GET_FUNC   = 1;
final int CMD_SET_DELAY  = 2;
final int CMD_GET_STATUS = 3;
final int CMD_I2C_IO     = 4;
final int CMD_I2C_BEGIN  = 1;  
final int CMD_I2C_END    = 2; 



public static void main(String[] args) throws USBException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int result = 0;

    libUSB_example2 ex = new libUSB_example2();
    result = ex.UsbInitLinux();

    System.out.println("\n" + "*******************************************************");
    if (result == 0) System.out.println("success");
    if (result == -1) System.out.println("usb-error");
    if (result == -2) System.out.println("write command status failed");
    if (result == -3) System.out.println("read data status failed");
    if (result == -4) System.out.println("cannot open device");
    if (result == -5) System.out.println("no converter found");
    if (result == -6) System.out.println("tiny-usb-Error");
    if (result == -7) System.out.println("parameter-Error");
    if (result == -8) System.out.println("usb claim/release-error");
    System.out.println("*******************************************************" + "\n");


}

    public int UsbInitLinux()  { 

        LibusbJava.usb_init();
        LibusbJava.usb_find_busses();
        LibusbJava.usb_find_devices();
        Usb_Bus bus = LibusbJava.usb_get_busses();
        Usb_Device dev = bus.getDevices();

        for(bus = LibusbJava.usb_get_busses(); bus != null; bus = bus.getNext()){
            for(dev = bus.getDevices(); dev != null; dev = dev.getNext()){
                if(dev.getDescriptor().getIdVendor() == 0x10c4 && dev.getDescriptor().getIdProduct() == -5536){
                    handle = LibusbJava.usb_open(dev);
                    System.out.println("device found");
                    System.out.println(dev.getDescriptor());
                    System.out.println("handle : " + handle + "\n");
                    if(handle == 0)
                          return -4;    
                }
            }
        }
        if(handle <= 0)
            return -5;
        retval = UsbSet(CMD_SET_DELAY, 10);
        if(retval != 0)
            return retval;
        retval = LibusbJava.usb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
        if (retval != 1) 
            return -8;
        return 0;
    }

    public int UsbSet(int cmd, int value) {     
        if(LibusbJava.usb_control_msg(handle, 
               USB_CTRL_IN, CMD_GET_STATUS, 0, 0, dummybyte, 1, 1000)  < 0) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      }  

}
```

---

Its output is:

> device found
>   Usb_Device_Descriptor idVendor: 0x10c4, idProduct: 0xea60
>   handle : 140182634002272
>
> ---
>
> usb-error
>
> ---

Answer (score 1):

The CP2102 that you are using can be accessed as a virtual serial port through the cp210x.ko in the kernel, or you can access the device directly through libusb as you are doing.

I'd recommend using the cp210x.ko driver and opening the device as a serial port (such as /dev/ttyUSB0). You can then communicate to it as a serial device using something like a Java `SerialPort` object. The reason for this is the device's protocol is abstracted and you only need to know how to write some serial port code to transmit or receive data.

If you want to truly access the device as a libusb device with direct USB access you'll need to follow the CP210x protocol. This can be found on the Silicon Labs website in AN571:

http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN571.pdf

Chances are your dummy control message is bogus, so the device will stall the request yielding the error you see. You will need to issue an interface enable request (`IFC_ENABLE` found in AN571) to start any communication with the device. This would be a good test control message to determine if you are connecting with the device or not.